# Windows Visual Studio 2019 doesn't detect iphone XR iOS 13.4.1

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, iosdeployment

I'm new to xamarin.  I wrote a simple "Hello World" app using VS 2019 on Windows 10 which runs successfully on the emulators.  I have an iMAC on my network and it is successfully connected to my Windows visual studio on Win10 machine. No update warnings or mismatch version error message(s) during the paring of the Windows VS to the remote iMac. On my list of emulators, I have a long list of emulators and "Remote Device" option.  All in all, all is well when I work with the emulators.

Now, when I connect my iPhone XR (iOS 13.4.1) using USB to my VS 2019 on Win10, the expected result would be that my device would show up along side of all the emulators so that I can deploy to the device for debugging.  My first question is whether or not that is the right assumption.  If it is, then in my case that doesn't happen.  When I start iTunes program on my Windows machine, it has no issues connecting to my iphone (I can do backup, restore, etc.).  Interestingly, in VS, the `Device Log` has no issues connecting to the connected iphone either.  My phone is listed on the drop down box on the top left hand corner of the screen.  At this point, I can only assume that is not a connection issue.

What I'm left with is some kind of mismatch setting on VS 2019 in Win10 or on my connected iphone that is causing VS 2019 on win10 not seeing my usb-connected iphone.  Any ideas what setting I should fiddle around with?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connect your iPhone to the iMac, not the Windows PC.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks.  So there is no way that I can deploy using VS on win10 that is paired to a iMac?  Geez..The iMac is in my son's room - he's going to see a lot of me coming and going.

Comment: @Zuzlx If Mac device not always around you , you also can connect to iPhone device Over Wifi .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **First** option, you need to connect iPhone over USB on Mac device , then you can debug in iPhone device .
- **Second** option ,If Mac device not always around you , you also can connect to iPhone device Over Wifi .

> An important part of the developer workflow is deploying to a device. Xcode 9 introduced the option of deploying to an iOS device or Apple TV through a network, rather than having to hardwire your devices every time you want to deploy and debug your app. This feature has been introduced in **Visual Studio for Mac 7.4** and **Visual Studio 15.6 release**.

This guide details how to pair and deploy to a device over the network : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/wireless-deployment?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you need to do is select "Debug|iPhone" or "Release|iPhone" from the build configuration menu.